# How to set up feature switch on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I want to apply a feature switch locally I do

```
MY_FEATURE=1 rails s
```

And How can I do this on heroku ?

This is how i push my code to heroku... so how can I add this `MY_FEATURE=1`

```
git push heroku master
```

I guess there is something to do in a Procfile, how should it be?

Comment: You can look at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up as a config var in heroku using either the web interface (your app -> settings -> config vars) or by setting it through the heroku CLI like so:

```
heroku config:set MY_FEATURE=1
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars for more details.